# Rails seeding loop with a has_one failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seed

I'm trying to seed my database with some fake data. I want each Prospect to belong_to a single User. My seed creates users but fails to create Prospects and I don't know why.

```
User.destroy_all
Prospect.destroy_all

50.times do

  u = User.new
  u.email = Faker::Internet.email
  u.password = "password"
  u.first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
  u.last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
  u.save

end

users = User.all
puts users

users.each do |user|
  p = Prospect.new
  p.id = user.id
  p.parent_first_name = user.first_name
  p.parent_last_name = user.last_name
  p.student_first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
  p.save
end
```

Here's my User and Prospect models

```
# prospect.rb
class Prospect < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  def full_parent_name
    name = "#{parent_first_name.capitalize} #{parent_last_name.capitalize}"
  end

end

# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :prospect

 ... lots of devise and Oauth stuff
end
```

My puts statement shows that User.all is finding 50 Users so I think that my issue is trying to create the `belongs_to` and the `has_one` is the problem. Should I be handling that a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks wrong :

```
  p.id = user.id
```

You don't want your Product to have the same id as your User. You could write

```
p.user = user
```

though.

## Alternatives :

Instead of

```
  p = Prospect.new
  p.user = user
  p.parent_first_name = user.first_name
  p.parent_last_name = user.last_name
  p.student_first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
  p.save
```

you could just write :

```
user.create_prospect(student_first_name: Faker::Name.first_name)
```

Since your Prospect belongs to a User, it shouldn't hold the same information in the database at its User. You could use `delegate` or define `parent_first_name` as `user.first_name`, without writing it to the DB.

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly my issue.